# Unable to edit any page (not site pages, just web part pages) of a Publishing site collection in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, error, publishing-page, edit

We have SharePoint Online environment at my organization and admins are not able to edit any pages on the entire site collection. Admins are able to edit site pages, but not pages. When i try to edit the page, it shows loading and just stays so. 
[image: Error]

Note: This is a Publishing site collection.

Everything was functioning fine till yesterday and all of sudden this issue arises in the morning. No updates were made on this page, that might have caused the issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any error in browser's console?

Comment: If you have any custom components, those would be suspect #1.

Comment: Yes we do have a lot of custom components on the site collection and a lot of custom scripts and references added to the masterpage. We did not do any recent modifications to the script. No console errors too. How do we figure out which script is failing?

Answer (score 0):

If it was a permissions issue, then you would see a "you do not have access to this page" message with a form to request access. It says the authenticity could not be verified - that could be an SSL issue. Seems like a network issue and not a SharePoint one.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: doesn't seem likely for SP Online.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that all the publishing pages cannot be edited?

Try to create a new publishing page and check the results.

You can also deactivate the publishing feature and then re-activate this feature to check the results.

In addition, you can try to use Fiddler Tool to monitor requests and responses to see what is failing. Fiddler will let you know exactly how long it takes to load the page, and break down each and every resource that is also loaded in order to render the page. This is also a great tool for determining what is and what is not being cached.